# Create wildcard for any number in link to block in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, wildcard

Someone is attempting some bad stuff on my site and I am tired of blocking the IP's he is using. So I want to prevent him from executing the code all together and redirect any such attempt to the local server. For that I use the following condition in my `.htaccess:`

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=http://213.246.61.125:2082/index.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule page.php http://127.0.0.1/index.php? [NS,S,L]`

Now, the thing is trying this from many different IPs on which this index.html is hosted as well. So I want to make a wildcard so that no matter the IP before the index.html the one trying it is always redirected to his local server.
I am not sure how to do this. I can not use an IP wildcard as you would elsewhere `(34.5.*.*)` cause this is a link. So I assume I have to use something like:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=http://([0-9]).([0-9]).([0-9]).([0-9]):2082/index.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule page.php http://127.0.0.1/index.php? [NS,S,L]`

But,  the above is not right but I have no idea how to adjust it for any combination of numbers. Maybe someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You should a plus sign after the `[0-9]` character ranges since you want to match one or more characters. Also note that

- the dots in your regexes should be quoted with a backslash. Otherwise they match any character.
- the parentheses in your `RewriteCond` are unnecessary.
- the `NS` and `S` flags in your `RewriteRule` are probably unnecessary.

I'd try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=http://[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+:2082/index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule page\.php http://127.0.0.1/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I have used your above example however I decided to add a .* to match anything after the .html cause I noticed they ended their attempts with a questionmark.
So, this is the syntax I used:
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=http://[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+:2082/index\.html.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule page\.php http://127.0.0.1/index.php [L]`

Now any requests with `http://*.*.*.*:2082/index.html?` or `http://*.*.*.*:2082/index.html` are redirected to the local server.
I think I am good to go like this, thanks again!